# how to map reg values to the ports of other module

Tags: verilog

i am an amateur in verilog. i am trying to call module divider. but i get errors like "Reference to vector reg 'qtnt' is not a legal net lvalue" in synthesis. i have tried using wires as inputs but when i tried to assign values to them an error message was recieved. please help

```
module euclid_mul(
  input[9:0] p0,p1,q0,
  input[19:0] tot,
  input clk,
  output reg [20:0] p2,
  output reg out_en,o1,o2
);
reg[20:0] dvr,dvd,qtnt,rem;
reg[9:0] ph;
reg[20:0] mul,res;
reg enable,f1;

initial f1=0;
initial enable=0;

divider div2(dvd,dvr,enable,qtnt,rem,f1);   

always @ (negedge clk)
  begin 
    if(f1==0) begin
      mul=q0*p1;
      ph=p0;
      res={11'b00000000000,ph[9:0]}-mul;
      if(res[20])
        begin
          o1=1;
          dvd=-res;
        end
      else
        dvd=res;
        o2=1;
        dvr=tot;
        enable=1;
      end
    end

    always @(posedge f1)
      begin
        if(res[20]) 
          begin 
            p2=tot-rem;
            out_en=1;
          end
        else
          begin
            p2=rem;
            out_en=1;
          end
        end
      endmodule
```

Comment: Is the 4'th port of the module div2 an input or an output.  If it's an input you should connect something to it.  If it's an output, it can be left open, but you should check your design if you really don't need that output.

Comment: the 4th port is an output port.My problem is that the values that i use as the inputs to the div2 instantiation are reg values and not net values.so please tell me how to assign reg values to wires in an always block or how to use the reg values as inputs to the instantiated module.

Comment: To get the sim running, disconnect everything from div2, tie inputs to 0, leave outputs. Then start adding what you think is correct until you see the syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get more response if you formatted the code so that it was easier to read. Something like the following:

I have also pointed out a section where I think you are missing a begin and end statement. 
Also inside clocked sections you often want to use nonblocking assignments `<=`.

Since you have not provided the divider module, I would prefer to see ports named rather than specified in order, it might help us to know what it is likely to do, even better label it with its direction and width.

```
module euclid_mul(
  input       [9:0] p0,p1,q0,
  input      [19:0] tot,
  input             clk,
  output reg [20:0] p2,
  output reg        out_en,o1,o2
);
reg [20:0] dvr,dvd,qtnt,rem;
reg  [9:0] ph;
reg [20:0] mul,res;
reg        enable,f1;

initial begin
  f1     = 0;
  enable = 0;
end

divider div2(dvd,dvr,enable,qtnt,rem,f1);   
// My prefered style to help us understand conectivity.
//divider
//  divider_i0(
//    .divisor( dvd ), //input  [20:0]
//    .result ( res )  //output [20:0]
//);


always @ (negedge clk) begin 
  if(f1==0) begin
    mul = q0*p1;
    ph  = p0;
    res = {11'b00000000000,ph[9:0]}-mul;
    if ( res[20] ) begin
      o1  = 1;
      dvd = -res;
    end
    else begin //There was a missing begin
      dvd   = res;
      o2    = 1;
      dvr   = tot;
     enable = 1;
    end //Missing End
  end
end

always @(posedge f1) begin
  if(res[20]) begin 
    p2     = tot-rem;
    out_en = 1;
  end
  else begin
    p2     = rem;
    out_en = 1;
  end
end
endmodule
```

Inputs can be `reg`s and driven from inside always or initial blocks, or wires driven from a single `assign` or another modules output.

Outputs should always be connected to wires, the module drives them.